# reading Json from PHP with javaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json, webserver, request

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
    class Sample{
    public $name = "N3mo";
    public $answer = "";
}
if(  isset( $_GET['request'] )  ){
    echo "Starting to read ";
    $req = $_GET[ 'request' ];
    $result = json_decode($req);
    if( $result->request == "Sample" ){
        $ans = new Sample();
        $ans->answer = " It Is Working !!! ";
        echo json_encode($ans);
    }else{
        echo "Not Supported";
    }
}
?>
```

Is there anything wrong

I want to send a JSON to this php and read the JSON that it returns using java script , I can't figure out how to use JavaScript in this , because php creates an html file how Can I use $_getJson and functions like that to make this happen ?!

I tried using

```
$.getJSON('server.php',request={'request': 'Sample'}) )
```

but php can't read this input or it's wrong somehow

thank you

Comment: Yes, you would need an ajax call. Just use a library like jQuery to do the heavy lifting or just google for examples of ajax calls.

Comment: where are you stuck?? Are you not getting result back in JS?? Are you using AJAX ??

Comment: Show your curernt javascript that is sending thsi data to the php script you have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out. It uses jQuery to load contents output from a server URL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX Load Test</title>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#button").click(function(event) {
              $('#responce').load('php_code.php?request={"request":"Sample"}');
          });
       });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Click on the button to load results from php_code.php:</p>
   <div id="responce" style="background-color:yellow;padding:5px 15px">
          Waiting...
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="button" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

Code below is an amended version of your code. Store in a file called php_code.php, store in the same directory as the above and test away.

```
<?php

class Sample
{
    public $name = "N3mo";
    public $answer = "";
}

if(  isset( $_GET['request'] )  )
{
    echo "Starting to read ";
    $req = $_GET['request'];
    $result = json_decode($req);

    if( isset($result->request) && $result->request == "Sample" )
    {
        $ans = new Sample();
        $ans->answer = " It Is Working !!! ";
        echo json_encode($ans);
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Not Supported";
    }
}
```

Let me know how you get on

Answer (score 0):

It would be as simple as:

```
$.getJSON('/path/to/php/server.php',
    {request: JSON.stringify({request: 'Sample'})}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

You can either include this in `<script>` tags or in an included JavaScript file to use whenever you need it.

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right path; PHP outputs a result and you use AJAX to get that result. When you view it in a browser, it'll naturally show you an HTML result due to your browser's interpretation of the JSON data.

To get that data into JavaScript, use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('output.html', function(data) {
  var importedData = data;
  console.log('Shiny daya: ' + importedData);
});
```